# what is the difference between the tag with prefix "javaee:" and not with "javaee:" in web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xml-namespaces

As the title, what is the difference between the tag with prefix "javaee:" and not with "javaee:".

i find we need to set the configuration by using the tag without "javaee:", and tag with prefix "javaee:" does not work

for example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

works

but

```
<javaee:welcome-file-list>
    <javaee:welcome-file>default.jsp</javaee:welcome-file>
    <javaee:welcome-file>default.html</javaee:welcome-file>
</javaee:welcome-file-list>
```

does not work.

i am using tomcat 8.5.6 as server.

below is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd ">
    <display-name>SQUEEN WECHAT</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/config/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: show your full web.xml especially starting tag declaration and I will explain..

Answer (score 3):

Read below for xml namespace. It is the basics of xml.

[image]

So in your **web.xml** if the declaration is like as follows:

```
<web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

you can write following without namespace.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If your **web.xml** looks like as follows that has a custom namespace declaration

(**Note: xmlns:javaee**) :

```
<web-app  xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
```

you have to write the same with namespace as follows:

```
<javaee:welcome-file-list>
    <javaee:welcome-file>default.jsp</javaee:welcome-file>
    <javaee:welcome-file>default.html</javaee:welcome-file>
</javaee:welcome-file-list>
```

It's just way how xml works. Nothing else.